# select2, unhide the already selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 drop down to allow multiple selections but it is removing the selected value from the drop-down list. 
How can I disable that?
I want to show all the values in the drop-down.

```
xyz.select2({ formatResult: formatElement, 
              formatSelection: formatElement, 
              closeOnSelect: false })
```

Comment: Please give some code

Comment: @Schneyer : Here is a code snippet, I am using for dropdown, 

xyz.select2({
    formatResult: formatElement,
    formatSelection: formatElement,
    closeOnSelect: false
})

I am trying to multiselect the options and also show the selected value in the drop-down list.

Comment: Please can you attach the screen shot of your issue ?

Comment: its similar to what is shown in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/LfhL33kc/1/

On  selecting a particular value, it disappears from the drop down list.